# Histrogram of maven dependencies over all projects (What is used how often)

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management, maven-dependency

Is there a way to generate somehow a Histogram of Maven Dependencies?
(number of usages over the library)

I would like to know for all of our projects (not necessary connected in any terms):

- What libraries/dependencies are used
- In what version they are used
- Form how many modules/projects they are used

Is there a way to extract this information with maven (or any other tool) form the POMs?
Do you have suggestions how to collect this info over many projects?

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a command:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

The `-Dverbose` option will show all dependencies, even the ones removed.

Read [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) for more info

Comment: That could go into the right direction. But What is `-Dincludes=commons-collections` for as I did not found it in the usage/goals/faq there. Further more the tree is nice but would still cause a lot of work to do to sum it up (flatten, merge, sum, ... for all projects) and the other output modes (to spare out the flatten) seems to work on Module/pom level only.

Comment: Yeah you'r right, I've removed that from answer. About the work to do, yeah, unfortunaly there's no other way: maven is powerful, but finding problem like these requires alot of digging. Had same problem few time ago and spent like 2 days for finding the problem... (ps: upvote the answer if was useful pls! :) )

Answer (score 0):

**IntelliJ Idea**

In IntelliJ Idea, open pom.xml file, right-click anywhere and select `Diagrams` -> `Show dependencies...`:

[image: IntelliJ Idea]

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2018.1 but I don't see this option. But if it is working like the module/class diagram that does not  help much, as I would have to do it manually on all modules to get the diagram (nice picture) but would have to manually check it for all of them and add them up.

Comment: I have IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.1.5